I am developing springboot application using gradle and want to have both thin and fat jars with slight difference
I want this application to be deployed on the server and running as well and I want it to be used as a dependency jar in another project. I want to exclude the resources folder only in the dependency jar(thin jar) and include it in an executable(fat) jar so that I can use it.
I tried using the code below in the build.gradle file. The gradle file excludes the resources folder from both thin and fat jars.
tasks.jar { processResources.exclude('*') }
I am using the below versions
gradle 8.8, java 21 and spring-boot 3.3.3
Let me know what more I can add to Gradle to have this jars in place.
Thanks

Now if only that would be documented. Specifiying a classifier will deliver 2 artifacts 1 executable (with classifier) and 1 default jar.

We can write a custom gradle task to archive this, below is the example sudo code
task thinJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set('thin')
    from sourceSets.main.output
    
    exclude('**/resources/**') // Exclude resources folder
    with jar
}

tasks.build {
    dependsOn thinJar
}


Hi SANN3, Thanks for the reply. I have tried adding this to my grade file but it is not excluding the resources folder from the thin jar it creates. This creates a separate thin jar that includes resources like the fat jar.
